# How do I smooth only the outside edges of a complex object?

Tags: edges

I would like to convert the edges on this object to a perfect circle and leave all other edges undisturbed.  What is the easiest way to do this?
[image: Help me turn this into a circle]

Comment: You can't "smooth edges" you need subdivisions for a smoother result. You will have a hard time doing it in your model due to poor topology choice. You should aim for a [quad based topology](http://topologyguides.com) if you wish to use subdivision surface modelling

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the quad based topology would be the answer on this. Please see my suggestion: I have added the blend. file for this as well.[image]

[image]